# python outputs None twice

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran the following code in Python 2.7.10:

```
count = 1
for i in (False, None):
    print count
    count += 1
    if i is None:
        print i
    if not i:
        print i
```

and the output was

```
1
False
2
None
None
```

If i run the code:

```
count = 1
for i in (False, None):
    print count
    count += 1
    if i is None:
        print i
```

the output is:

```
1
2
None
```

Why is None printing twice in 1st case.

Comment: `if not i` executes when `i` is None.

Comment: `None` is false. So, `if not i` will be true when `i` is `None`.

Comment: Negative ticks deserved

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something; *both* `if` conditions are true:

```
>>> i = None
>>> i is None
True
>>> not i
True
```

`None` is [considered false in a boolean context](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing); *not* false is true; quoting the documentation:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
>
> [....]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

With both `if i is None:` and `if not i:` passing, you print `i` twice.